# Grouping and Total on one Column Values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have this group in a table. Where I need to display one value on the top and rest according to its alphabetical order.

**Table**

```
     Column1      Value#1  Value#2

     Alpha         12      26
     Beta          65     745
     Gamma        987      87
     Pie            7       2
     Non-Beta     132     426
     Zeta         112     266
```

How can I display it in the below format...

**Table**

```
    Column1      Value#1  Value#2

     Non-Beta     132     426
     Alpha         12      26
     Pie            7       2
     Zeta         112     266
      Total       263     720

     Beta          65     745
     Gamma        987      87
      Total       1057    832
```

I could display Non-Beta on the top by using the below expression in the sorting tab in the group Property.::

```
=IIF(Fields!Column1.Value = "Non-Beta", "A" + Fields!Column1.Value, "B" + Fields!Column1.Value)
```

But how do I Display it according to the above format. Values Come from one column (Column1)

**EDIT**

This is the output I got after the operation that Ian specified...

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a group based on an expression like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!Column1.Value = "Beta" or Fields!Column1.Value = "Gamma"
  , "Group2"
  , "Group1")
```

i.e. if *Beta* or *Gamma*, include in one group; everything else gets grouped together.

[image]

Include a Header and a Footer row with the group.

Apply the sorting expression to the Tablix as required.

The report will look something like this in the designer:

[image]

End results looks like your requirements:

[image]

Comment: Hello Ian, it works as you said, But in column it shows as Group 1 and values and Group 2 and values...........It does not display the Column names...

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing your report... Are you happy with my output as a baseline? I think what might have happened for you is that some fields in the group header row got created referencing the grouping expression? In the above example the column headers are just text entries in the table header row, not field references in the group header row. If this doesn't clarify things can you please add a screenshot of the relevant rows in Designer and Preview?

Comment: Hey Ian, I have updated the question with a screenshot. Can you please suggest me a way to get around with that